# Can't fix these 2 errors when trying to run React Native ios app

Tags: react-native

I'm having a terrible time with my React Native environment. After doing a pull from the main branch at the little startup I've been working for, I cannot get `npx react-native run-ios` to work. I've tried all the usual suspects like:

```
1. reinstall node modules from package.json
2. reinstall pod in /ios
3. reinstall cocoapods 
4. made sure to clear all caches
5. tried different versions of Node
6. reinstalled Node, NVM, Xcode, Cocoapods from the React-Native docs
7. made sure I have a .env file 
8. restarted my computer (you'd be surprised)
```

The errors I get are either:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:332:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:369:19)
    at UnableToResolveError.buildCodeFrameMessage (/Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:304:17)
    at new UnableToResolveError (/Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:290:35)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:168:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:353:43)
    at /Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:271:42
```

Or

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4` from ``: 

None of these files exist:
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.svg|.svg)
  * debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4/index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx|.native.svg|.svg)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native-2/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native-2/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native-2/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
    at /Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native-2/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42
    at /Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native-2/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1096:37
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native-2/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (/Users/demiansims/Development/ColorTV/colortv-react-native-2/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:119:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Researching any of the errors of above have led me to the steps I took above but nothing seems to work.

I'm not using Expo for development. I'm using React-Native CLI.

Comment: Does Android run fine?

Comment: I stumbled upon the same error. I managed to fixed it by disabling first my Debugging. And by refactoring my App.js because of the Redux problem.

Comment: I'm running in the same issue both on Android and iOS.
@xsephtion What were the refactoring changes in App.js you did?

Comment: Yes I am still experiencing this issue. But however this error "
Error: Unable to resolve module `./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4` from ``:"  or "Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read" doesn't affect my debugging at all. I highly suggest to clear your browser's cache and everything then run "react-native start --reset-cache"

Comment: I ran into this issue when I upgraded expo from 39 to 40 (i know you aren't using expo). Further debugging pointed to it loading an entry module that doesn't exist, and becoming an issue after an HMR. For some reason it kept trying to load an entry module that I wasn't using. Still no resolution on my end.

Comment: same here after upgrading expo. No idea how to solve it yet.

Comment: Can you show me your app.json file? (if you have). Maybe I found the solution

Comment: did you find any solution for this?@Demain Sims

Comment: I apologize but no, I never found a solution although it's working now. I did update Xcode and reinstalled Cocoapods. I also updated Node. I'm not sure which of these did the trick.

Comment: I did all of the things mentioned here and it still didn't work.  Uninstalled the app from the simulator and ran it again and it worked.  No idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Update your node installation to latest LTS version (14.16.0 now), and it should fix this issue.

I recommend using `nvm` to manage your node versions. This can also help you switch versions quickly if needed.

To install the latest LTS version using `nvm` you can just run `nvm install --lts`

Answer (score 1):

Ok. so i ran into this same problem.

Assert that you still have index.js in your root directory. I know it sounds silly, but someone here deleted the index.js and I did not notice and I got the exact same error. after re-creating the index.js. The error was gone.

BTW just in case this is my index.js

```
import whyDidYouRender from "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render";
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import React from "react";
import { enableScreens } from "react-native-screens";

import { App } from "./src/App";
import { setup } from "./src/config";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  whyDidYouRender(React, {
    trackAllPureComponents: false,
  });
}

enableScreens();
setup();

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in the Expo client or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```